# Recovering deleted answered questions

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

There were 2 questions which were answered, but the author deleted them almost instantly.

Original questions:

1. [Alternatively eliminating vertexes from graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041641/alternatively-eliminating-vertexes-from-graph)
2. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042782/graph-clustering-algorithm

I managed to get the Google cached webpages...but no sign of answers.
Also Archive.org doesn't have it.

1. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042782/graph-clustering-algorithm
2. http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041641/alternatively-eliminating-vertexes-from-graph

I found that 10k+ users can view a deleted question. Since I don't have enough rep to post on Meta, I'll assume a risk and ask here that maybe a qualified user can recover them.

Answer (score 6):

The question [Alternatively eliminating vertexes from graph](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041641/alternatively-eliminating-vertexes-from-graph) got a good answer. The OP left a thank-you comment and deleted the post. I voted to undelete.

The question [Graph clustering algorithm](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1042782/graph-clustering-algorithm) got no answers, no comments, and 4 votes to close by the time it was deleted by the author. I'd rather let it stay deleted.

Comment: The first is now undeleted and can no longer be deleted by the OP.